# AppCompat v7 and DatePicker render issue

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, datepicker, android-appcompat

Recently I have read a chapter about dialogs in *The Big Nerd Ranch Guide (2nd edition)* and I have done everything by the book. However there are some issues, which are not mensioned in the book. Preview area of *Intellij Idea* doesn't work correctly with AppCompat themes.

This is my current theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

And this is what I have in preview area:
[image]

In the Internet I have read that using **Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar** may help. It removes the message, but ActionBar dissapeares also.

Oh, and **DatePicker** doesn't work with both and any **Material Design**:
[image]

This is just a render issue, because both themes work fine on devices. *Can someone try to preview DatePicker in IDEA and Android Studio with AppCompat theme?* May be this is just an IDEA issue.

***P.S.*** **dialog_date.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/dialog_date_date_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
/>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.criminalintent" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
                android:name=".CrimeListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CrimePagerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Whole project:** https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4653F2D263EA4131!21585&authkey=!AESze90_ZZ0p9WY&ithint=folder%2cproperties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Switching Themes

If you look at the declaration for `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, it aliases directly to `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` in AppCompat's values/themes.xml file:

```
<!-- Platform-independent theme providing an action bar in a dark-themed activity. -->
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

[source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml)

This isn't aliased in any of the other device configurations (e.g. values-v23/themes.xml, values-v18/themes.xml, etc). Have a look at the resouces for AppCompat [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res). This means that for every device, `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` will *always and only* alias to `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

The docs for the `Base` theme make this even more clear:

> Themes in the "Base.Theme" family vary based on the current
>   platform version to provide the correct basis on each device. You
>   probably don't want to use them directly in your apps.
>
> Themes in the "Theme.AppCompat" family are meant to be extended or
>   used directly by apps.

[source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/master/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes_base.xml)

So your switching from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Base.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar` will never affect how things are displayed on actual devices and really isn't a change. The fact that Android Studio behaved differently is a problem with Android Studio (which I was unable to reproduce using your code on AS 2.0 preview 9).

### Problem with Android Studio

I'll say that the Design tab has always been a bit flaky. It's getting better but hasn't always played nice, especially with support library stuff. To change your app's theme (even if what I said above wasn't true) just to make the Design tab look pretty is probably a bad idea. Think about your users. If you *really* want to know what your screen looks like, then deploy it to a real device or emulator.

### Dialogs

I was also unable to reproduce your Dialog problem in AS 1.4 (stable) or AS 2.0 preview 9 (canary, ATM). But since your entire layout file is a `DatePicker`, I don't think you will get much benefit. This is even less beneficial when you consider that your `DatePicker` will be displayed in a dialog (which the Design tab is unable to simulate). I don't mean to sound harsh but you might just have to bite the bullet and use an emulator or physical device.

Answer (score 1):

Make your style.xml look like this, toolbar will show up:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And your **DatePicker** needs to loo like this:

```
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:id="@+id/datePicker" />
```

If you need **CalendarView** in your xml add this insted of **DatePicker**:

```
<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView1" />
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I've tried it and it solved **Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**, but DatePicker is still not visable.

Comment: I've added a P.S. section

Comment: Adding android:datePickerMode="spinner" will solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want spinner. I want calendar view to be available for Android 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Shitty Android Studio 1.5.0 should be updated to 1.5.1. So easy